# Drag and drop a movieclip through 2 array

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have six dragable movieclip with an instance name store in this array:

```
var dragArray1:Array = [drag1, drag2, drag3, drag4, drag5, drag6];
```

I have some 5 movieclip to be a hitTestObject that six movieclip above and store that instance name too in this array:

```
var mArray1:Array = [mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, mat5];
```

Here some stuff of variable:

```
var currentClip1:MovieClip;
var startX1:Number;
var startY1:Number;
```

Here is my code to make a looping drag an drop for dragArray1:

```
for(var ia:int = 0; ia < dragArray1.length; ia++) {
    dragArray1[ia].buttonMode = true;
    dragArray1[ia].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown1);

}

function item_onMouseDown1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    currentClip1 = MovieClip(event.target);
    startX1 = currentClip1.x;
    startY1 = currentClip1.y;
    currentClip1.startDrag()
    addChild(currentClip1)
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp1);

}
```

**Here is my "unWorking code"**. i want this code to make the dragArray1 hitTestObject mArray1, when dragArray1 hitTestObject mArray1 the x and y of dragArray1 is equal to mArray1, sorry if my english are so bad

Here's the code:

```
function stage_onMouseUp1(event:MouseEvent):void {

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp1);
    currentClip1.stopDrag();

    for(var ma:int = 0; ma < mArray1.length; ma++){

        if(currentClip1.hitTestObject(mArray[ma])){
            return;
            trace("hit")
            currentClip1.x=mArray1[ma].x;
            currentClip1.y=mArray1[ma].y;
        }else{
            currentClip1.x=startX1;
            currentClip1.y=startY1;
        }
    }
```

}

I just want every movieclip in dragArray1 can hitTestobject in any movieclip in mArray1 randomly.

Comment: in the `if-loop`, did you try to put return as last command? Just before `else`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the position of your **return;** statement. Calling it prior the other 3 lines causes them to not execute.

Hence, the fix is simply placing return; to the end:

```
trace("hit")
currentClip1.x=mArray1[ma].x;
currentClip1.y=mArray1[ma].y;
return;
```